# Resource ID from Fragment always comes out to 0

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to access some images from a Fragment which is attached to the MainActivity but I always get the ID as 0. Could you please help me figure out why? Below function always returns true

```
public boolean isResourceIdZero(Object testObject){
    String uri = "@drawable/" + testObject.getImageName().toLowerCase() + ".png";
    int resId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(uri,"drawable",getActivity().getPackageName());
    if(resId==0)
        return true;
    testObject.setImageId(resId);
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: No guarantees, but what if you remove "@drawable/" and ".png" parts from the id?

Comment: @Android777 that did work! Thanks for your help! If you can note that down in the answer section, I would be happy to accept that as an answer!

Comment: glad, it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As practice has showed the solution to this riddle was in removing "@drawable/" and ".png" parts from the resource `uri`.